# Sencha Cmd 6 build is creating directory with "${ext.dir}" name

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

Sencha Cmd v6 when built creates a directory under current ext app with name "${ext.dir}", changing config for `ext.dir` in `sencha.cfg` does not help

How to disable it from generation directory with name "${ext.dir}" instead with some other sensible name.

Versions
Ext v6
Sencha Cmd 6.1.0

Comment: Have you find an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use template for own project. 
Look at "output" section inside app.json.

Comment: It does mention ${ext.dir} but should not it be replaced with value of ext.dir

Comment: This variable is not aveilable from your project. `output` config section must be looks like:

    
    "output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
        "page": "index.html",
        "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
        "js": "${build.id}/app.js",
        "appCache": {
            "enable": false
        },
        "resources": {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources",
            "shared": "resources"
        }
    }